# Is it a load bearing wall?

Tags: walls

Is it a load bearing wall? I do not think so, but want to confirm. There is also a switch on this wall that I want to move to the adjacent wall. So, is there a law that says that this work should be done only by a licensed contractor? Will the electrical inspector demand everything in the house be up to code when they inspects the work done?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Please see [ask]. You need to ask one clear question per post and you need to provide enough information so we can help.

Comment: Any laws will depend on your local.  Probably not load bearing, but is thick enough to be hiding stuff.  Can you see underneath or above any plumbing, air vents?

Comment: Can’t tell, are you in a high wind or seismic zone?

Comment: Is there an upstairs in the building? What's above this location?

Comment: It's pointless asking about local laws without divulging the locality of the building. Could be anywhere in the world, with any rules applicable.